# Python plotting with two y axis and only one set of data points

Tags: python, plot

I'm not sure if this is feasible, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

I'm working with a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
| Distance | Height | Wind Speed |
| -------- | ------ | ---------- |
|   0.25   |   10   |   5.2      |
|   0.56   |   15   |   3.2      |
| ........ | .......| ...........|
```

Distance is a function of both height and wind speed. I want to plot (scatter or line) the distance values with the height and wind speed values as two separate y axes. Is this possible? I've tried doing this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(df['Distance'], df['Height'])
ax.plot(df['Distance'], df['Wind Speed'])
```

but it plots two separate lines, one as `Distance` vs `Height` and one as `Distance` vs `Wind Speed` when I'm trying to get one line as a function of both `Height` and `Wind Speed`. Is this possible to do? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get a single plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Height":[10,15,20], "Windspeed":[5.2,3.2,4.5]})
df["Distance"]=df["Height"]*df["Windspeed"]
df["Distance"].plot()
```